# symfony1.4 ajax request frontend controller factories

Tags: ajax, symfony1, symfony-1.4, configuration-files

I have a frontend controller and there I want to make a module for Ajax requests.
The problem is that this controller uses to much configurations and that slows the request down heavy. I need a solution to make new configurations just for the Ajax.

If I make a new controller it works nicely but then I don’t get the other modules in the frontend controller with templates ..

Any solutions?

Comment: Can you post some codes

Answer (score 0):

Don't make your module in the controller. Create it within your library for all your custom class modules.

You could use Namespace within your controller to use it.

```
$ajaxMod = new \Path\to\mod\class();
```